# BlocProvider conditionally passing in Bloc, still disposing when using BlocProvider.value

Tags: flutter, bloc

Main screen - sometimes goes directly to a `DraftPage`
Sometimes goes to a `ThreadPage` which then goes to the same `DraftPage`.

The `ThreadPage` and the `DraftPage` both use a `ThreadEditorBloc`. In the case where I go straight to the `DraftPage`, I instantiate a new bloc from the `DraftPage`. In the case where I go through the `ThreadPage`, I instantiate the bloc there, and I pass it into the `DraftPage`.

I want the bloc to be disposed when the editing page is done (when I "Save Draft") only if it was instantiated in that page. To handle this, I am using `MultiBlocProvider`, and providing `BlocProvider.value` in cases where there is a `ThreadEditorBloc` passed into `DraftPage`, and regular `BlocProvider` with `create` method when there is not.

However, it still seems like the Bloc gets disposed even when I pass one in, because if I try to edit, go back to the `ThreadPage` and try to edit again, it won't let me add new events because it says the bloc has been disposed. Is there any other issue that could be causing this?

Here is the `ThreadPage` with the button to launch the `DraftPage`:

```
@RoutePage()
class ThreadPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Thread thread;
  ThreadPage({required this.thread, super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<ThreadEditorBloc>(
      create: (context) => ThreadEditorBloc(
        getIt<ThreadRepository>(),
        thread,
        getIt<ThreadWatcherBloc>(),
      ),
      child: const ThreadPageScaffold(),
    );
  }
}

class ThreadPageScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  const ThreadPageScaffold({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ThreadEditorBloc, ThreadEditorState>(
      buildWhen: (p, c) => p.thread != c.thread,
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              'View Thread',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                onPressed: () {
                  context.router.push(TweetDraftRoute(
                    thread: state.thread,
                    threadEditorBloc: context.read<ThreadEditorBloc>(),
                  ));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: BlocBuilder<ThreadEditorBloc, ThreadEditorState>(
            buildWhen: (p, c) => p.thread != c.thread,
            builder: (context, state) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: state.thread.tweets.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ThreadTweetTile(
                    thread: state.thread,
                    tweet: state.thread.tweets[index],
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class ThreadTweetTile extends StatelessWidget {
  Thread thread;
  Tweet tweet;

  ThreadTweetTile({
    super.key,
    required this.thread,
    required this.tweet,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        child: Card(
          // Some stuff in here
        ),
        onTap: () => {
              context.router.push(DraftRoute(
                thread: thread,
                threadEditorBloc: context.read<ThreadEditorBloc>(),
              )),
            });
  }
}
```

Here is the `DraftPage` with the two different types of blocs (created vs. passed in):

```
class DraftPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Thread? thread;
  ThreadEditorBloc? threadEditorBloc;
  DraftPage({this.thread, this.threadEditorBloc, super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<ThreadWatcherBloc>(
          create: (context) => getIt<ThreadWatcherBloc>(),
        ),
        if (threadEditorBloc != null)
          BlocProvider<ThreadEditorBloc>.value(value: threadEditorBloc!),
        if (threadEditorBloc == null)
          BlocProvider<ThreadEditorBloc>(
            create: (context) => ThreadEditorBloc(
              getIt<ThreadRepository>(),
              thread,
              getIt<ThreadWatcherBloc>(),
            ),
          ),
      ],
      child: DraftPageScaffold(),
    );
  }
}

class DraftPageScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  const DraftPageScaffold({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<DraftPageScaffold> createState() => _DraftPageScaffoldState();
}

class _DraftPageScaffoldState extends State<DraftPageScaffold>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  bool isKeyboardVisible = false;
  double keyboardHeight = 0;
  final double bottomSheetHeight = 65;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final keyboardVisibleHeight = mediaQueryData.viewInsets.bottom;

    setState(() {
      isKeyboardVisible = keyboardVisibleHeight > 0;
      keyboardHeight = keyboardVisibleHeight;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Edit Tweet',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                saveDraft(context);
              },
              child: Text('Save Draft'))
        ],
      ),
      body: // body widget
  }
}

void saveDraft(BuildContext context) {
  context.read<PurchaseBloc>().add(PurchaseEvent.incrementDraftCount());
  context.read<ThreadEditorBloc>().add(const ThreadEditorEvent.saveThread());
  context.read<ThreadWatcherBloc>().add(const ThreadWatcherEvent.refresh());
}
```